# Plum tree giving fruit during winter

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, flowering, plums

I have a plum tree that usually gives fruit during summer. But today I've noticed something very strange: there are some fruits in it. The tree is even completely leafless as it usually is during winter, but it has some fruits and flowers. What could be happening?

Comment: Hi, where are you and can you add a picture?

Comment: Check if there has been strong lights on the tree at night.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know in which country you live but if the winter is not that cold then your plum tree was not in a dormant state and thinks that it is spring so it is going to flower and make fruits.

The thing is, if at some point there are some frost then it will destroy the flowers and the already grown fruits so you won't have anything during summer.